# Invalid column name 'RNumber' - Trying to implement pagination using PHP and MS SQL

Tags: php, sql-server

I'm trying to implement a LIMIT OFFSET query using MS SQL for the purpose of implementing Pagination to my products on a website together with PHP and PDO, but I get the following error: **"Invalid column name"**

My query

```
SELECT OITM.ItemCode,OITM.ItemName,ITM1.Price , 
OITM.CardCode,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY OITM.ItemName DESC) AS RNumber 
FROM OITM INNER JOIN OCRD ON OCRD.CardCode = OITM.CardCode 
INNER JOIN ITM1 ON OITM.ItemCode = ITM1.ItemCode 
WHERE OITM.frozenFor='N' AND PriceList=1 AND U_Publish='Y' 
AND RNumber >= 1 AND RNumber <= 2
```

Not to sure what is wrong here

Comment: Looks okay at first glance. Have you tried putting the whole expression into brackets? -- ie from `ROW_NUMBER()` to the end of the expression before `AS RNumber`.

Comment: @Spudley - Tried the brackets and it produces the same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need a `HAVING` clause. You can use a cte function or a subquery. Like this:

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT OITM.ItemCode,OITM.ItemName,ITM1.Price , 
    OITM.CardCode,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY OITM.ItemName DESC) AS RNumber 
    FROM OITM INNER JOIN OCRD ON OCRD.CardCode = OITM.CardCode 
    INNER JOIN ITM1 ON OITM.ItemCode = ITM1.ItemCode 
    WHERE OITM.frozenFor='N' AND PriceList=1 AND U_Publish='Y' 
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    CTE
WHERE
    RNumber >= 1 AND RNumber <= 2
```

Or with a subquery like this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
        SELECT OITM.ItemCode,OITM.ItemName,ITM1.Price , 
        OITM.CardCode,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY OITM.ItemName DESC) AS RNumber 
        FROM OITM INNER JOIN OCRD ON OCRD.CardCode = OITM.CardCode 
        INNER JOIN ITM1 ON OITM.ItemCode = ITM1.ItemCode 
        WHERE OITM.frozenFor='N' AND PriceList=1 AND U_Publish='Y' 
    ) AS t
WHERE
    t.RNumber >= 1 AND t.RNumber <= 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use neu defined names in the Where condition, you have to put in the HAVING clause.

```
SELECT OITM.ItemCode,OITM.ItemName,ITM1.Price , 
OITM.CardCode,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY OITM.ItemName DESC) AS RNumber 
FROM OITM INNER JOIN OCRD ON OCRD.CardCode = OITM.CardCode 
INNER JOIN ITM1 ON OITM.ItemCode = ITM1.ItemCode 
WHERE OITM.frozenFor='N' AND PriceList=1 AND U_Publish='Y' 
HAVING RNumber >= 1 AND RNumb
```

Comment: Tried the having claise vur get the same issue